# BizTalk 2013 WCF-WSHttp Send port

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am calling a third party service. Binding information contains TransportType as `Name="WCF-BasicHttp"`. I have consumed this service in my orchestration. I need to create send port with WCF-WSHTTP in BizTalk admin console. But I am getting below error. I have set security as NONE.

*Error information:*

> System.Net.WebException: Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service   The client and service bindings may be mismatched

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the security is a server side point. you have to use the same binding as the service from the server side.

Answer (score 1):

If the binding specifies basic-http binding, if there any specific reason to create send port with WCF-WSHttp binding ?

Have you tried creating the send port with WCF-Basichttp binding ?

Comment: Yest its working with WCF-Basichttp binding .But we need to use WCF-WSHttp binding ..Is this possible?

Comment: @bigB Why do you *need* to use WCF-WSHttp, especially if it's working with basic?  Also, is this a SOAP Service?

Comment: the third party hosting the service who must implented a security behaviour for the clients. You are just a client and you had to deal with its service transport/security needs. If you need any extra security, the ervice provider must implement it and communicate to the cinsumers the way to call it.